# Closure Compiler EXTERNS for PIXI.js - custom object parameter annotations

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc, pixi.js

I am preparing externs file for pixijs library to work with closure compiler.
The only problem I am having so far is with custom object parameters. Here is a short example:

pixi.js source:

```
/**
 * Set the style of the text
 *
 * @param [style] {object} The style parameters
 * @param [style.font='bold 20pt Arial'] {string} The style and size of the font
 * @param [style.fill='black'] {string|number} A canvas fillstyle that will be used on the text eg 'red', '#00FF00'
 * @param [style.align='left'] {string} Alignment for multiline text ('left', 'center' or 'right'), does not affect single line text
```

closure compiler output:

```
lib/pixi-externs.js:3266: WARNING - Parse error. invalid param name "style.font"
* @param [style.font='bold 20pt Arial'] {string} The style and size of the font
      ^

lib/pixi-externs.js:3266: WARNING - Bad type annotation. missing closing ]
* @param [style.font='bold 20pt Arial'] {string} The style and size of the font
                        ^

lib/pixi-externs.js:3267: WARNING - Parse error. invalid param name "style.fill"
* @param [style.fill='black'] {string|number} A canvas fillstyle that will be used on the text eg 'red', '#00FF00'
      ^

lib/pixi-externs.js:3268: WARNING - Parse error. invalid param name "style.align"
* @param [style.align='left'] {string} Alignment for multiline text ('left', 'center' or 'right'), does not affect single line text
      ^
```

How can these pixijs annotations be adapted to closure compiler annotations?

If there is no way to achieve this through annotations, could I overcome this by defining a new object ?

```
* @param {PIXI.TextStyleObject} style The style parameters
```

and creating a separate TextStyleObject object definition like so ?

```
PIXI.TextStyleObject = {};
PIXI.TextStyleObject.font;
PIXI.TextStyleObject.fill;
PIXI.TextStyleObject.align;
```

What is the correct way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use a record object to do this:

```
/** @param {{
 *        font: string,
 *        fill: string,
 *        align: string
 *      }} object
 */
```

If you find yourself re-using the same record object more than once, you can use a typedef to alias it:

```
/** @typedef {{
 *        font: string,
 *        fill: string,
 *        align: string
 *      }}
 */
 var PixiStyleOptions;

/** @param {PixiStyleOptions} object */
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there a way to specify a default value, like in pixi there is: [style.fill='black'] ?

Comment: No. This is for type information only. It has no bearing on actual code execution.

Comment: That makes sense. Last quick sub-question: Can I specify optional parameters with `=` suffix as usually when defining a @typedef ? e.g. `{{ font: string, fill: string, align: string= }}`

Comment: Unfortunately not in a record object. For optional, use `string|undefined`.